# How to do string named format in Elixir without interpolation?

Tags: elixir

I want to do named string formatting, and I don't want to use interpolation because the string will be fetched from CSV.

Suppose I have string data from CSV that I parsed

```
str = [
   "Hello %{name}, do you come from %{country} ?",
   "Did %{name} just arrived from %{country} ?",
   "Today, %{name} will go to %{country}",
   "Today, %{name} will join us"
]
```

In Ruby I can do this:

```rb
data = {name: "Julio", country: "Nirvana"}

str.each do |s|
  puts str % data
end

# Hello Julio, do you come from Nirvana ?
# Did Julio just arrived from Nirvana ?
# Today, Julio will go to Nirvana ?
# Today, Julio will join us
```

what is the equivalent in elixir?

I don't mind using hex library

Comment: In ruby [`String#%`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) is not doing any sanitization for strings, which means for strings it’s an exact equivalent for interpolation. Would you mind to elaborate please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a two-level [`comprehension`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1) combined with [`String.replace/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#replace/4) to replace the placeholders with their corresponding values.

```elixir
strings = [
  "Hello %{name}, do you come from %{country} ?",
  "Did %{name} just arrived from %{country} ?",
  "Today, %{name} will go to %{country}",
  "Today, %{name} will join us"
]

data = %{name: "Julio", country: "Nirvana"}

for string <- strings do
  for {key, value} <- data, reduce: string do
    string -> String.replace(string, "%{#{key}}", value)
  end
end
```

Output:

```elixir
[
  "Hello Julio, do you come from Nirvana ?",
  "Did Julio just arrived from Nirvana ?",
  "Today, Julio will go to Nirvana",
  "Today, Julio will join us"
]
```

There is no problem using interpolation here, because we are only interpolating the map keys, not evaluating arbitrary code.

---

The same thing using [`Enum.map/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#map/2) and [`Enum.reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#redu) instead of comprehensions:

```elixir
Enum.map(strings, fn string ->
  Enum.reduce(data, string, fn {key, value}, string ->
    String.replace(string, "%{#{key}}", value)
  end)
end)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Regex.replace/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Regex.html#replace/3) to do the replacements in one go. This would be more efficient than @Adam's `for` + `String.replace/3` solution, especially if there a large number of elements in `data`:

```elixir
strings = [
  "Hello %{name}, do you come from %{country} ?",
  "Did %{name} just arrived from %{country} ?",
  "Today, %{name} will go to %{country}",
  "Today, %{name} will join us"
]

data = %{"name" => "Julio", "country" => "Nirvana"}

for string <- strings do
  Regex.replace(~r/%{(\w+)}/, string, fn _, key -> Map.fetch!(data, key) end)
end
|> IO.inspect()
```

Output:

```elixir
["Hello Julio, do you come from Nirvana ?",
 "Did Julio just arrived from Nirvana ?",
 "Today, Julio will go to Nirvana",
 "Today, Julio will join us"]
```

The regex `/%{(\w+)}/` matches `%{` followed by one or more letters or numbers (`\w+`) followed by `}`, capturing the letter/number sequence, which we use in the second argument of the replacement callback to fetch the right replacement value from `data`.

---

One more difference compared to @Adam's solution is that this will raise an error if the string contains an interpolation that does not exist in `data` instead of silently ignoring it:

```elixir
strings = ["Today, %{name} will go to %{city}"]
```

raises

```elixir
** (KeyError) key "city" not found in: %{"country" => "Nirvana", "name" => "Julio"}
    :erlang.map_get("city", %{"country" => "Nirvana", "name" => "Julio"})
```

(You can handle such errors in a different way if you want by changing what the replacement function does.)

Comment: If there are more keys, sure, but with the provided example, Regex is twice as slow on my Core i5 (it starts to win at about 8 keys). With Elixir there are so many nice built-in options I always treat Regex a last resort.

Comment: Yup, for two, `String.replace` should certainly be faster. Still, a benefit of this method is that it lets you catch typos inside `%{}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`EEx`](https://hexdocs.pm/eex/EEx.html) which is part of Elixir and doesn't need to be installed from Hex:

```elixir
strs = [
   "Hello <%= name %>, do you come from <%=country %> ?",
   "Did <%= name %> just arrived from <%= country %> ?",
   "Today, <%= name %> will go to <%= country %>",
   "Today, <%= name %> will join us"
]

data = [name: "Julio", country: "Nirvana"]

Enum.map(strs, fn str -> EEx.eval_string(str, data) end)
```

`EEx` allows to execute arbitrary Elixir code though, so this would be a security risk if you need to work with user-provided CSV files.

Comment: oh cool, I completely forgot about EEx formatting, it could be an option